# RecyclerView never refresh with viewmodel in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, viewmodel

My onBindViewHolder is only called the first time (when I initialize the empty object). When you set my list variable, the list is not updated. Here are my classes:

```
class BankAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<BankAdapter.MyHolder>() {
private var bankList: List<Bank> = ArrayList()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
    println("onCreateViewHolder")
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.bank_list_item, parent, false)
    return MyHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
    println("onBindViewHolder")
    val currentBank = bankList[position]
    var importo: String
    if (currentBank.saldo > 1000000) {
        importo = "${currentBank.saldo / 1000000}M €"
    } else if (currentBank.saldo > 1000) {
        importo = "${currentBank.saldo / 1000}K €"
    } else {
        importo = "${currentBank.saldo} €"
    }
    holder.txt_nome_banca.text = currentBank.nome
    holder.txt_indirizzo_banca.text = currentBank.indirizzo
    holder.txt_iban_banca.text = currentBank.iban
    holder.txt_saldo.text = importo
}
fun setBankList(bankList: List<Bank>) {
    println("setBankList")
    this.bankList = bankList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    println("getItemCount " + bankList.size)
    return bankList.size //+1 //Aggiungo un elemento per valorizzare l'item per NUOVO
}

inner class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var cl_new = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_new)
    var cl_item = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_item)
    var txt_nome_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_nome_banca)
    var txt_iban_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_iban_banca)
    var txt_indirizzo_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_indirizzo_banca)
    var txt_saldo = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_saldo)
}
```

And this is my Fragment. In my viewModel observer, i call setBankList method inside my adapter:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var mView: View
val bankAdapter = BankAdapter()
private lateinit var bankViewModel: BankViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val rvBank = mView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_banks)
    rvBank.adapter = bankAdapter
    rvBank.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mView.context)
    bankViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BankViewModel::class.java)
    bankViewModel.getAllBank().observe(this, Observer { t ->
        bankAdapter.setBankList(t)
    })
    return mView
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        HomeFragment().apply {
        }
}
```

}

getItemCount method is called after i set the new List. Size is right, but onBindViewHolder It is not called

Comment: can you show your activity code or where you set your adapter for your recyclerview ?

Comment: Is your `setBankList` method ever called?

Comment: @Ircover, Yes In my fragment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your arraylist is loosing reference. Try this way

```
class BankAdapter(private val  bankList: ArrayList<Bank>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BankAdapter.MyHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
            println("onCreateViewHolder")
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.bank_list_item, parent, false)
            return MyHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
            println("onBindViewHolder")
            val currentBank = bankList[position]
            var importo: String
            if (currentBank.saldo > 1000000) {
                importo = "${currentBank.saldo / 1000000}M €"
            } else if (currentBank.saldo > 1000) {
                importo = "${currentBank.saldo / 1000}K €"
            } else {
                importo = "${currentBank.saldo} €"
            }
            holder.txt_nome_banca.text = currentBank.nome
            holder.txt_indirizzo_banca.text = currentBank.indirizzo
            holder.txt_iban_banca.text = currentBank.iban
            holder.txt_saldo.text = importo
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            println("getItemCount " + bankList.size)
            return bankList.size //+1 //Aggiungo un elemento per valorizzare l'item per NUOVO
        }

        inner class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var cl_new = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_new)
            var cl_item = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.cl_item)
            var txt_nome_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_nome_banca)
            var txt_iban_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_iban_banca)
            var txt_indirizzo_banca = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_indirizzo_banca)
            var txt_saldo = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_saldo)
        }
    }
```

and Now in Fragment initialize adapter with empty arraylist and later populate arraylist and then you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mView: View
    private lateinit var bankAdapter : BankAdapter
    private lateinit var bankViewModel: BankViewModel
    private val  bankList = ArrayList<Bank>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val rvBank = mView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_banks)
        bankAdapter = BankAdapter(bankList)
        rvBank.adapter = bankAdapter
        rvBank.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mView.context)
        bankViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BankViewModel::class.java)
        bankViewModel.getAllBank().observe(this, Observer { t ->
            bankList.addAll(t)
            bankAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
        return mView
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            HomeFragment().apply {
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes:

1. Kotlin automatically generates getters and setters for properties, so you can remove 
   `getAllBank()`.
2. On `setBankList(bankList: List<Bank>)` you are passing a reference to a new list, in order for recyclerview to work correctly it must point to the same list all the time.

So what you need to do instead is:

```
private var bankList: ArrayList = arrayListOf<Bank>()

fun setBankList(bankList: List<Bank>) {
    println("setBankList")
    this.bankList.clear()
    this.bankList.addAll(bankList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: Yes. in my case 2 items, i've debugged

Answer (score -1):

Inside `RecyclerView.Adapter` use `PagedListAdapter`.

I think this link will help you [Android RecyclerView Pagination](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-recyclerview-pagination-with-paging-library-using-mvvm-rxjava-dagger-2-and-livedata-b0489ecbbfc0)